# How to optimize complex calculation query execution time?

Tags: mysql, geolocation, query-optimization, table-index

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT *, (
        6371 * acos (
            cos ( radians(33.577718) )
            * cos( radians( `Latitude` ) )
            * cos( radians( `Longitude` ) - radians(115.846524) )
            + sin ( radians(33.577718) )
            * sin( radians( `Latitude` ) )
        )
    ) AS `distance`
FROM `geopc_cn_places_grouped`
WHERE `Latitude`!=33.577718 AND `Longitude`!=115.846524
HAVING `distance` < 200
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
LIMIT 30;
```

The query execution is always somewhere between 3.5 and 4 seconds.

I have applied a composite index to `Latitude` and `Longitude` by running `ALTER TABLE geopc_cn_places_grouped ADD INDEX index_Longitude_Latitude(Longitude, Latitude);`, but it doesn't reduce the execution time.

I want to know why it's running slow and what possible optimizations can be done.

The slow query log message shows this

[image: Slow Query Log]

and this is the `EXPLAIN SELECT` query

[image: EXPLAIN SELECT]

Table Structure...

[image: Table Structure]

and lastly, here is the table index list

[image: Table Indexes]

Comment: Look into creating geospatial indices on MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html

Comment: ok, checking it now...

Comment: Do not use a formula - use spatial datatype and ST_Distance() function.

Comment: got it, thanks, I'm studying it at the moment

Comment: Caution:  `latitude != ...` may fail to work correctly because of roundoff error.  Consider using an `id` of the place to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query as written isn't [sargable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean).  That is, it cannot exploit any index. So, each time you run it, you use that big spherical cosine law formula for every row in your table. It's a [full table scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-scan-avoidance.html).  It's likely that most of your slowness comes from the  table scan, because modern computers do the math pretty quickly once they have the data in RAM.

But, you're in luck. Your search looks for points within a 200 statute mile radius of your candidate point. That means you can usea  `WHERE ... BETWEEN` clause to eliminate points that are more than 200 miles south or north (latitude) of your starting point.

To do this you need to know there are 69.0 statute miles, 60 nautical miles, and 111.045 km in each degree of latitude. Therefore you should search for point ± (200/69)   So.... try a query like this.

```sql
SELECT *, (
        6371 * acos (
            cos ( radians(33.577718) )
            * cos( radians( `Latitude` ) )
            * cos( radians( `Longitude` ) - radians(115.846524) )
            + sin ( radians(33.577718) )
            * sin( radians( `Latitude` ) )
        )
    ) AS `distance`
FROM `geopc_cn_places_grouped`
WHERE `Latitude`!=33.577718 AND `Longitude`!=115.846524
  AND Latitude BETWEEN 33.577718 - (200/69) AND 33.577718 + (200/69)
HAVING `distance` < 200
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
LIMIT 30;
```

Then create an index on your `Latitude` column.

```
CREATE INDEX latsearch ON geopc_cn_places_grouped(Latitude);
```

The `Latitude BETWEEN` clause I suggest will then do an [index range scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html) and so skip many of the rows in your table. That's the classic SQL way of making queries faster.

This is a simplification of the ideal answer to this question. [I wrote up this problem here](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/).

Comment: You're a genius! The execution time is now cut into half, I'm completely satisfied with the result, superb, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your query must compute the distance for every row.  The quick solution is to use a "bounding box".  This limits the number of rows to test to a latitude stripe or longitude stripe.

Details (and more advanced speedups):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql